# How to undo "Revert changes from this revision" in tortoisesvn

Tags: tortoisesvn, revert

I used "Revert changes from this revision" option in tortoisesvn,
because I wanted build my project without all changes that I made in one particular revision.
After that I wanted all changes back and updated folder in tortoisesvn,
but nothing happened, no files was updated.
What is that means?
It means I do not correctly reverted changes and my build will contain them?

Please explain to me how to correctly revert changes from one revision to get project build in visual studio without them, and then get all that modifications back again?

Comment: See if this documentation helps http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-rollback.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out:
In tortoiseSvn right button click on working copy, then select "Check for modifications".
All reverted files should display as "Modified".

To undo revert need to select all that files, then right button click on em and select "Revert".

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're on the right lines, to get those changes back in you could:

1. Revert changes from revision (as you have done)
2. Commit
3. Create a tag for your new project build
4. Checkout the revision prior to the revert you just did
5. Commit again

That should have you back as you were previously without the revert, with the repository in the same state, but you now have a tag saved for your project build.